# Turn string to nested array php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to turn a string into a nested array
Here is my string:

```
a/b/d.docx
```

and I wanted to be like this:

```
array(
    "name" => "a",
    "type" => "folder",
    "sub" => array(
        "name" => "b",
        "type" => "folder",
        "sub" => array(
            "name" => "c.docx",
            "type" => "file",
            "size" => "20"
        )
    )
)
```

This is the code that I have so far

```
$items = explode('/', $strings);
$num = count($items);
$num = --$num; 
$temp = array();
foreach($items as $keys => $value) {
    $temp[$keys] = array(
        "name" => $value,
        "type" => "folder",
        "items" => $temp[++$keys]
    );
    if($keys == $num){
        $temp[$keys] = array(
            "name" => $value,
            "type" => "file",
            "size" => "20"
        ); 
    }
}
var_dump($temp);
```

I am trying this functions but this only turn string into a single array and it also can't do the 'items' line.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.
Note that the path is virtual and doesn't exist.
**UPDATE:** How can I add path to each array??for example,`"path"=>"a/b"`

Comment: You're going to have comment a little, I can't follow what you are doing and what you are trying to do.

Comment: `$num = --$num` is useless, you can use `--$num` it will be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$strings='a/b/d.docx';

$items = explode('/', $strings);
$num = count($items)-1;

$root= array();
$cur = &$root;

$v='';

foreach($items as $keys => $value) {

    $v = $v.$value;
    $temp = array(   "name" => $value,  "path"=>$v,  "type" => "folder",    "items" => "");
    if($keys == $num){ 
        $temp = array( "name" => $value, "path"=>$v, "type" => "file", "size" => "20"); 
    }
    $v= $v.'/';

    if($keys==0) {
        $cur = $temp;
    }
    else
    {
        $cur['items'] = $temp;      
        $cur = &$cur['items'];
    }
}
var_dump($root);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.How can I add path to arrays?for example "path"=> "a/b"

Comment: I edited my answer post, the answer is easy to understand, you  have to  try by yourself to learn something

Comment: Can you please explain the items part?

Comment: The core idea is recursion, [Casimir et Hippolyte](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)'s answer is elegant, he pops element from the tail, I use method from the head, and connect each element's items head to tail, it's all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also have one more question. How can I put the items JSON output in brackets? like: "items":[{ .....

Comment: [There](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) full of examples, very recommend you to look and see ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that:

```
$path = 'a/b/d.docx';

$parts = explode('/', $path);

$result = [ 'name' => array_pop($parts), 'type' => 'file', 'size' => 20 ];

while ($parts) {
    $result = [ 'name' => array_pop($parts), 'type' => 'folder', 'sub' => $result ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.How can I add path to arrays?for example "path"=> "a/b"

Answer (score 0):

Try recursion:

```
public function testAction(){
    $sString = 'a/b/c/d.exe';
    $aExploded = explode('/', $sString);
    var_dump($this->_parse_folder_rec($aExploded));
}

private function _parse_folder_rec($aExploded){
    $aResult = [];
    $aResult['name'] = array_shift($aExploded);
    if($aExploded){
        $aResult['type'] = 'folder';
        $aResult['sub'] = $this->_parse_folder_rec($aExploded);
    }else{
        $aResult['type'] = 'file';
        $aResult['size'] = 20;
    }
    return $aResult;
}
```